# The London safes and their mysterious combinations

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, story

*Here's the first riddle I invented for Puzzling SE. Hope you'll enjoy solving it.*

This story takes place during World War II. A German spy is assigned the task to sneak overnight into a military base near London and steal secret documents of utmost importance.

The documents are kept inside 30 safes of reinforced unbreakable steel, and each safe is protected by a numeric secret code. Therefore the only way to get the documents is to open each safe with the correct code. If the wrong code is entered, the safe will immediately trigger a siren which will alert all military personnel, so the spy has only one try available.

German Intelligence was able to provide the spy with the following information: 
First, it looks like the codes were not chosen at random, but instead follow some unknown pattern. Second, they intercepted half of the safes' codes, which they communicate to the spy:

```
Safe   Code
#1     2
#2     4
#3     6 
#4     8
#5     10
#6     12
#7     14
#8     16
#9     18
#10    20
#11    22
#12    24
#13    26
#14    28
#15    30
```

The second half of the safes' codes is still unknown. German Intelligence advises the spy to delay the mission until all codes have been discovered; however, the spy believes that the pattern is obvious, as a safe's code appears to be the double of the safe's number.

That same night, the spy enters unseen the military base, finds the safes, silently opens each one of them with the correct code and steals the documents. Everything goes well from safe #1 to #17.

**However, when the spy enters the code 36 on safe #18, the safe doesn't open; its alarm triggers, and the spy is captured.**

**Can you find why? If not, continue reading.**

A few weeks later, the military base has sixty more safes delivered. The codes on these safes are programmed following the same pattern.

After the end of the war, the commander of the base is asked by the High Command to compile a list of all safes and codes. He produces the following document:

```
Safe   Code   Safe   Code   Safe   Code   Safe   Code   Safe   Code   Safe   Code
#1     2      #16    32     #31    28     #46   -42     #61    34     #76    46     
#2     4      #17    34     #32    30     #47   -40     #62    36     #77    48    
#3     6      #18    25     #33    32     #48   -38     #63    38     #78    50
#4     8      #19    38     #34    34     #49   -36     #64    40     #79    52   
#5     10     #20    40     #35    36     #50    30     #65    42     #80    25    
#6     12     #21    42     #36    38     #51    32     #66    44     #81    27    
#7     14     #22    44     #37    40     #52    34     #67    46     #82    29
#8     16     #23    46     #38    42     #53    36     #68    48     #83    31
#9     18     #24    48     #39    44     #54    38     #69    50     #84    33
#10    20     #25    50     #40   -54     #55    40     #70    34     #85    35
#11    22     #26    52     #41   -52     #56    42     #71    36     #86    37
#12    24     #27    54     #42   -50     #57    44     #72    38     #87    39
#13    26     #28    56     #43   -48     #58    46     #73    40     #88    41
#14    28     #29    58     #44   -46     #59    48     #74    42     #89    43
#15    30     #30    26     #45   -44     #60    32     #75    44     #90    38
```

**Can you find now how the codes were chosen - and hence why the spy failed?**

**Hint 1**

> *There is an unique solution for the riddle. Don't try to find overcomplicated formulas. There is more than just mathematics -- in fact, although there is quite a bit of calculations, the mathematics involved are very basic. To crack the code, you'll have to do some lateral thinking.*

**Hint 2**

> *Language is important. The story takes place in Great Britain because the riddle is related to the English language. The nationality of the spy is irrelevant.*

**Hint 3**

> *Observe how the British chose the secret algorithm to fool spies. "Code of safe $n = 2 \times n$" is a red herring -- it looks like it is the solution, but is valid only up to safe #29 with the exception of safe #18. The units for each "ten" follow a pattern, but each "ten" breaks the pattern. Where would you find such a pattern?*

Comment: the spy had a brain-fart and entered the wrong number?

Comment: @APrough No, the spy entered the code 60.

Comment: @dr01 Does it have something to do with time? like 60 is represented as 00 or some other number? Also does the year have any significance or it will have no impact on the puzzle?

Comment: @kanchirk No, representation of minutes or other time units has nothing to do with that. The year is specified only to add some atmosphere. I've removed it to avoid putting people to a false scent.

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed on the locks?

Comment: Key GC&CS cryptanalysts moved from *London* to Bletchey Park before *WW2* (which is where Enigma was cracked) Is this anything to do with it?

Comment: I'm going to assume that safe #30 isn't a safe that automatically sets off the alarm no matter what, even though that would be a brilliant security system.

Comment: I'm thinking the key is that it's London, I'm trying to think of something that happened in 2's 29 straight times but then changed on the thirtieth.

Comment: @Kingrames Yes, safe #30 is exactly like the other safes.

Comment: @Kingrames I've had a similar idea. 30 safes doesn't have to imply 30 documents. Could indeed be a tricky failsafe on behalf of the british.So if your pattern works 29 times and you get a document each time, you have no reason to assume the 30th wouldn't be valuable.

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code To solve the riddle, you don't need to know anything about Bletchley Park, the Enigma machine, or even WWII.

Comment: Different angle: Would there be a reason for the spy to want to get caught? If so, he deliberatly set off safe 60?

Comment: @TimCouwelier No, of course. It's in the spy's interest to open all 30 safes stealthily and run away with all the documents.

Comment: Hmm... In London, is there some sort of system that would count up until you reach a certain point and then it would stop counting up? I'm thinking something like accrued commissions or something along those lines. the makers of the locks would probably get a kick out of it. Like "after 30 days, you earn PTO at the rate of 59% no matter what" or something like that.

Comment: Oeis.org finds only sequences for which 60 is the next number. The Jacobus problem is close, which goes up to 64 and then back to 2.

Comment: I'm concerned that this is a question which is too broad -- ie. where we're (unintentionally) expected to read your mind. There are several plausible answers below and specifically APrough's is still valid according to the text right now. I think the puzzle needs some extra detail and narrowing down so that the wrong answers are wrong because of information that's contained in the puzzle, not just because it doesn't match the answer you had in mind.

Comment: @lorimer Agreed. I didn't want to give out the solution by putting too many details but I realized that the question frustrated you. I've added some hints, you may vote to reopen or ask for more if you feel that the riddle is too obscure.

Comment: @APrough Apologies, I just realized I might have somehow misled you with my answer (now deleted) concerning negative numbers. Negative numbers are allowed on the locks; in fact, if there were e.g. a safe #40, it would need a negative code to open. However, the 30 safes mentioned in the riddle all have positive numbers as codes.

Comment: @dr01 Has it something to do with the number of alphabets in German language?

Comment: @TimCouwelier Actually yes there would be, historically all German spies in Britain during WWII were either captured, or turned themselves in. Every single one.

Comment: Something, something... crossing the Greenwich meridian?

Comment: Is it related to the language, i.e. English/German?

Comment: @SeraphCheng You're getting closer! If nobody gets the right answer I'll start posting the codes for more safes. This should help in solving the riddle.

Comment: @kanchirk You mean the number of letters in the German language? The language/nationality *of the spy* is irrelevant.

Comment: Don't quite understand the closevotes and downvotes. In its original form this one wasn't good, but as it is now it seems fine, assuming the answer isn't terrible.

Comment: Well, originally I hadn't been able to get back before now :)  At the moment, it won't let me vote to reopen (remove my close vote) for some reason; unsure why, because I think the changes made to the question are fine.  I'm sorting out the problem.

Comment: @BenAaronson As it currently stands, IMO the _question_ is still very broad. There's lots of information in comments scattered all over the place (allowing negative numbers for example, or the fact that there answer still holds if there were more than 30 safes for example), but as it stands I don't feel the question is a good example for this site.

Comment: @lorimer It was already closed then reopened once. Maybe your close vote was in the first set.

Comment: "That same night, the spy enters unseen the military base, finds the safes, silently opens each one of them with the correct code and steals the documents." That statement seems contradictory to the one immediately following.. I do not want to be the guy picking apart semantics but I want to confirm that the spy was UNABLE to open the 30th safe and that was not a sly little redaction on your part.

Comment: I wish the author can edit the question, such that the scattered information in the comments is also included. It would be nice to have a "Hint 3" showing codes after safe number 30, too.

Comment: @Portali5t That's a reasonable question. The spy tries the code 60 and the safe fails to open, triggering the alarm. There are no word tricks.

Comment: @SeraphCheng Good point. For a more dramatic effect I had included only the first 30 safes in the riddle (the pattern failing on the 30th), but now I realize this made the riddle too difficult to solve. I've added in the riddle the codes of 30 more safes. This should allow you to find the secret pattern and solve the mystery.

Comment: In its current form, it's fine, but previously it was certainly too broad. As a general rule, you need at least 5 distinct numbers in a series to show the pattern, and if the pattern deviates from some obvious norm, you need more. NOW, we have the required basic first step. It's even numbers, they count up, and at 30, 40, 50, and 60, they deviate from the pattern by some even number. That's a good starting point. If you think of it abstractly, we have the even numbers series, and 4 points of deviation. That should work better.

Comment: I tried to find something in the non-decimalized British currency - which was changed in 1971 - but I can't find a pattern that matches.

Comment: @dr01  I think the title is too generic, may I suggest a rename: $$\mathbf{Safes\ and\ Codes:\ German\ Doubling}$$
Or something else that you might like, but the present title is quite terrible.

Comment: @Anachor How about "The London safes and their mysterious combinations"?

Comment: @EngineerToast Sorry, you're on the wrong path. Nice idea though.

Comment: Is the code of safe #70 140?

Comment: No, it's 34, sorry.

Comment: Seems it is very difficult for a non-British to solve this riddle.

Comment: Not really; all you need to know to find the solution is some basic English and basic arithmetic.

Comment: @SeraphCheng Can you tell me by which method you concluded that safe #70 has code 140?

Comment: @dr01 `ten`, `twenty`, `seventy` contains the vowel `e`; `thirty`, `fifty`, `sixty` contains the vowel `i`; `forty` contains the vowel `o`; `y` is ignored.

Comment: The negatives in the forties does show us one thing: the number in the one's place seems to add 2 to whatever number is formed by a function applied to the ten's place.

Comment: Maybe I have made things overcomplicated. What if I simply map A to Z as 1 to 26? Gotta give it a whirl.

Comment: @SeraphCheng You're getting closer to the solution.

Comment: Following your 4th hint, I think `ty` seems to equal 20. Thus `sixty` equals `six` + `ty`. `thirty`, `forty` and `eighty` break the pattern as `thir`, `for` and `eigh` are no numbers. `Twenty` **should** breake the pattern (and so should `fifty`), but it doesn't, so this approach might as well be completly wrong.

Comment: @Christoph Your approach is correct. Now try to find why #20 doesn't break the pattern.

Comment: Seems to me that `thirty` is not breaking the pattern (as it should) either. Above `twenty`, `forty` and `eighty` are the only weird multiple of tens here.

Comment: @Aioros Hint #5 might be of help.

Comment: @dr01 could it be that #18 is actually 25, not 36?

Comment: @Christoph It appears that not only you found the solution but also a terrible mistake I've made. I've corrected the question in the less uglier way possible. Sorry.

Comment: While I enjoyed watching the solution, there is ZERO chance one could've solved this based on the initial given info for the riddle...

Comment: Very nice riddle. I am too dumb to solve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> To get the code of a safe, write down the safe's number as a word, replace the letters with numbers using the following matching, and finally add them together.
>
> ```
>  e: 0    f: 5    g: -62  h: 67
>  i: 0    l: 8    n: 9    o: -7
>  r: -72  s: 0    t: 11   u: 82
>  v: 5    w: 0    x: 12   y: 9
> ```
>
> (the other letters do not appear in the numbers)

How I got there:

> After the last hint (and all the comments and thinking before) it was pretty clear to me, that each letter in the word had to have some value which then would add up to the safe's code. Obviously the usual matching `a = 1, b = 2, ...` would not fit, so I had to do some calculations based on the assumption that `t+y = 20` which I guessed after hint 5.
>
> ```
>  t+y = 20
>  t+w+e+n+t+y = 40 => t+w+e+n = 20
>  t+e+n = 20 = t+w+e+n => w = 0
>  t+w+o = t+o = 4, t+e+n = 20 => t+t+o+n+e = 24
>  t+t+o+n+e = 24, o+n+e = 2 => t+t = 22 => t = 11
>  t+y = 20, t = 11 => y = 9
>  t+e+n = 20, t = 11 => e+n = 9
>  e+n = 9, o+n+e = 2 => o = -7
>  n+i+n+e = 18, e+n = 9 => n+i = 9 => i = e
>  n+i+n+e+t+e+e+n = 38, n+i+n+e = 18 => t+e+e+n = 20
>  t+e+e+n = 20 = t+e+n => e = i = 0, n = 9
>  f+i+f+t+y = 30, t+y = 20 => f+i+f = f+f = 10 => f = 5
>  f+i+v+e = f+v = 10 => v = 5
>  s+e+v+e+n = s+v+n = 14 => s = 0
>  e+l+e+v+e+n = l+v+n = 22 => l = 8
>  s+i+x = s+x = 12 => x = 12
>  f+o+r+t+y = -54 => r = -72
>  f+o+u+r = 8 => u = 82
>  t+h+r+e+e = t+h+r = 6 => h = 67
>  e+i+g+h+t = g+h+t = 16 => g = -62
> ```
>
> I hope that helps to understand the way I found the solution and also how the codes are calculated.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Congratulations!

Comment: I wanted to say that the error in the original question threw us a bit off and that the number replacements are too weird, but I'm entirely too baffled from seeing that this actually works somehow.

Comment: @Aioros Thanks. I apologize again for my error; it slipped somehow during the calculations of the Diophantine equations for the 90 codes. It shouldn't have spoiled *too much* the riddle.

Comment: Nah, not for me at least. I definitely wouldn't have figured it out all the same.

Comment: @Aioros, after 20 it is not a surprise it works (since "Y" appears for the first time in "twenty" and 0-9 repeat all the time), but it is interesting how with just 16 letters (12 non-zeros) you can get all of the first 20 numbers (I assume this is why the OP had to multiply by 2?). Very nice indeed.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan Thanks. It is not mandatory to multiply by 2. This kind of mathematical recreation (known as *neomerology*) is usually done with the same values i.e. ONE=1, TWO=2, etc. I just wanted to make a riddle that was somehow different.

Comment: @dr01, I guessed your system didn't have a solution for ONE=1, TWO=2, etc. due to problems modulo 2 and this is why you multiplied by 2. Now when I think about it though, 14, 16, 17, 19 repeat the digits 4, 6, 7, 9 with added teen at the end, so basically we have 16 degrees of freedom and 16 numbers to encode (1-13+15+18+20), which generally should be possible. Still, the coincidence is interesting and also a bit baffling why you have so many zeros among the letter values.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan Using the same values works well for numbers up to 10. For bigger numbers, it must be E=0 (because SIXTEEN = SIX+TEN) and I=0 (because THIRTEEN=THREE+TEN). If you're working with the same values, this makes N=4.5 because of NINE=9. The reason I multiplied by 2 was also to have a riddle with only integers.

Comment: @dr01, yeah I guessed that's why you multiplied by 2. Still, it was very close for the system to be unsolvable, which is what makes your problem so nice.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan Unfortunately it's not possible to fit 18 in the pattern: T is supposed to be 0 because of EIGHTEEN=EIGHT+TEN, but it was previously set as 11 by other constraints.

Comment: @dr01, oh I see, it seems you have changed it from 36 to 25 since the previous time I checked.

Comment: Excellent. How did you get to this solution?

Comment: Any proof that this is the ONLY solution? I'm not convinced this is unique.

Comment: after reading all comments and thinking for two an hour , i still unable to understand the answer. can you please explain more and step by step please.

Comment: @SeraphCheng I added some explanation

Comment: @KBusc If you solve the equations you'll see that this is the only solution. You can find other values that hold true if you consider a smaller subset of numbers (e.g. from 1 to 10 safes).

Answer (score 8):

The code should have been

> 0

I believe that the codes for each safe are equivalent to

> $($The next safe # in the sequence $\times 2) -2$.  Since Safe 30 is at the end of the sequence, technically Safe 1 would be next in sequence $(1 \times 2) -2 = 0$

Comment: Too easy. Sorry, wrong answer. :)

Comment: @dr01 Is it the wrong answer because you say it's the wrong answer, or is there enough information in the question to deduce that it's the wrong answer? That's the hallmark of a great puzzle (i.e. not one with multiple 'correct' answers, where the 'one answer to rule them all' lies with the Asker going "because I say so")

Comment: @MattTaylor The riddle would still work with 50 safes, but in this case this answer wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @dr01 You mean if there were 50 safes it would still fail at 30, not 50?

Comment: @dr01 In that case, would it make sense to extend the Puzzle as such? If that doesn't change the solution or its validity, then isolating the correct answer from those which are plausibly correct given the information (such as this one) can only be a good thing.

Comment: @BenAaronson Yes, it would still fail at 30, and all subsequent ones (31, 32, etc).

Comment: @MattTaylor I'll wait a little and, if nobody still comes up with the correct answer, I'll add some hint. :)

Comment: @dr01 It's not a hint I'm asking for, just improving the puzzle so that the fact that this answer is wrong is clearer in the question, as otherwise the engineer in me just wants to go "It's correct according to the specification of the puzzle, therefore it's correct (ner nerny ner ner)" =P

Answer (score 5):

The code should have been

> 2

Explanation:

> The story plays in the leap year 1944. The British picked the codes day by day, and simply doubled the number of the current day.  The numbering started on Feburary 1 (code $2*1=2$), Feburary 2 (code $2*2=4$), $\ldots$, Feburary 29 (code $2*29=58$), March 1 (code $2*1=2$).

Comment: I like this, but based on the fact that the OP originally had 1943 as the year (then removed it), and stated "The year is specified only to add some atmosphere", I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: Wrong, please try again. Date or time have no influence on the code.

Answer (score 5):

### Partial Answer

The code has something to do with the digits of the safe number.  If the code to safe $n$ is denoted by $C(n)$, then we can see that:

$$
C(n) = 2\left[f\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor\right) + (n~\text{mod}~10)\right]
$$

(The multiplication by two is because all code values are even.)

We know the values of $f$ for $0$ through $6$:

$$
\begin{align}
f(0)&=0\\
f(1)&=10\\
f(2)&=20\\
f(3)&=13\\
f(4)&=-27\\
f(5)&=15\\
f(6)&=16\\
f(7)&=17
\end{align}
$$

We are hinted that the answer has to do with the *location* of the safes, which leaves me to believe that $f$ is related to the *English spelling* or *pronunciation* of the numbers.  In particular, it seems to me as if there is some relationship between *thirty*/*thirteen*, *fifty*/*fifteen*, etc., although $f(4)$ breaks this pattern.

Comment: Forty is spelled differently from fourteen, maybe.

Comment: @f'' Good catch!  I actually never noticed the missing "u" before!

Comment: +1 for getting close to the solution! Hint: the solution doesn't involve complex mathematical formulas.

Comment: @dr01 Is that a hint that my $C(n)$ is wrong?

Comment: @2012rcampion Yes, the secret pattern can't be found by a mathematical function alone. (Or, at least, that would surprise me!) Your post contains the solution; take some time to develop it. Tomorrow I'll post another hint if nobody has made any progress.

Comment: @dr01 Remember that a mathematical function is any mapping from one set to another... so the answer must be a function (if the question is well-posed).  I might restate my question as, "is there some choice of $f$ such that the above $C$ produces the same results as your procedure for choosing the combination?"

Comment: @2012rcampion In this sense, yes, there is a function that can be applied to get the combination of any safe -- otherwise there would be no riddle to solve :)

Comment: @dr01 Let my try asking in a different way: if the numbers of two safes have the same tens digit, will the difference in their combinations always be twice the difference in their numbers?

Comment: @2012rcampion Yes, that's an effect of the pattern.

Comment: Is the formula a function only of the safe, or also of the code from the previous safe?

Comment: @DrXorile $C(n)$ is not a function of $C(n-1)$.

Comment: @DrXorile The combination code of safe $n$ is a function of safe $n$ only.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is too broad.

Anyway, the code might have been

> 0 or 1.

According to the formula:

> $code=2*num\pmod{59}$
>   or
>  $code=2*num\pmod{60}$

Comment: Agree this is too broad. Perhaps the answer is `1:00` because --- I don't know, clocks or something.

Comment: Wrong, please try again. Date or time have no influence on the code.

Answer (score 3):

> I think I know how the code works but can't figure out the critical bits. Basically if you assume that values one to twenty are C(n)=2*n then every safe after that has a code that is equal to the sum of the codes of the constituent parts i.e. code(twentyone) = code(twenty)+code(one) code(thirtyone)=code(thirty)+code(one) and so on It would be nice to know how code(thirty), code(forty), code(fifty) and code(sixty) are calculated

Comment: +1 because you're on the right path. The answer to your last sentence is contained in hint #2. Once you find it, you have solved the riddle.

Comment: Another possible clue is that the only true outliers are 40(-56) and 80(25). You could argue that all other Code(x:ty) =Code(x:teen). Forty and eighty are written and pronounced differently than fourteen or eighteen and I think that has something to do with how their codes are calculated

Comment: Good insight. That's an effect of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code is

> 62

Based on the idea that the code is

> Each safe number ($n$) is mapped onto double the $n$th number that is not the sum of 4 distinct nonzero squares. This would mean the 30th safe was mapped to 62.

It could also be that the code is

> Each safe number ($n$) is mapped onto double the $n$th number that has 2 or fewer distinct prime factors. Then $n=1,\ldots,29$ maps to $2n$ and 30 maps to 62.

Or it could be:

> Each safe numbered ($n$) maps to double the $n$th number that cannot be expressed in form $p+q^2+r^3+s^4$, where $p, q, r, s$ are primes. Then $n$ maps to $2n$ for $n\in{1,\ldots,29}$ and 30 maps to 64

Obviously I used oeis.org to find the above, but it does suggest that the question is a bit broad

Comment: It doesn't say the 30th safe, it says : *at **safe #30**, the alarm triggers, and the spy is captured.*

Comment: It's a minor change.

Comment: Changing a puzzle's wording to fit your answer is not "minor" in my opinion.

Comment: I'm saying changing my answer is a minor change.

Comment: The 30th safe is safe #30, point. There are no wordplays or tricks in the riddle. You can imagine that each safe has a label on it with its number.

Comment: I can't understand why this makes any difference at all, but I'll adjust the wording to make it more "compliant". Are you saying the answer is not correct?

Comment: He added in a comment that safe 40 would end up with a negative number. Your suggested method doesn't allow for that to occur.

Comment: Sorry, none of these is the right answer. In addition, trying to find the solution using only mathematics won't work.

Answer (score 1):

**An answer without pure math**

Safe number 1 starts with code = 2.
Stepsize between safes is 2, except when exception fits as described hereunder.

Exeption-check:

When safe number written as English word ends with "y", replace "y" by "een" and look for that English word in the previous safe numbers. If found, take the code of that safe number. 
If not found, but there exists a word with a difference of only one letter, the following rule will apply:

- fetch previous replacement's safe number, i.e. of the "een" word (**not** safe's code)
- substract this safe number from actual safe number
- take code of the safe found this way
- multiply by -1 (because initial search was negative)

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by all of this. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: Also, i've not heard of 'twenteen'.

Comment: Too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The code should have been

> 26

Partial explanation

> Each ten breaks the pattern, except 1-29. Instead of the expected `thirty * 2` the code uses `thirteen` (very similar in pronunciation): `thirteen * 2 = 26`. The same applies for fifty `fifteen * 2 = 30`, sixty `sixteen * 2 = 32`, seventy `seventeen * 2 = 34`, ninety `nineteen * 2 = 38`. This didn't work for eleven and twelve, which is why safes #1-29 follow a regular pattern.

However, I'm still in the dark on #40 and #80.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't really answer the question of what is the secret algorithm used to create the codes :) . Note that the algorithm must work for *all* safes; trying to explain why *some* of the safes have that code won't work.